# Riskless Pricing of an European Option; How to calculate?

Tags: finance

I don't know if this question could be asked/answered here but since there is a "finance" tag...I'll give it a shot.

I am asked to show that the value of an option below obtained by 1. Risk-neutral 2. Risk-less portfolio argument are the same. I managed the value of the option calculated by the risk-neutral version.

> Current price of a stock is $\$40$. It is known that it either increases of decreases by 12.5% every 3 months over the next 6 month period. The risk-free interest is $8%$ by continuous compounding. Verify that the values of a 6-month European put option on the stock with strike price $\$40$ obtained by the riskless portfolio and the risk-neutral arguments are the same.

Simply, my notes mention a super tiny bit of the pricing via risk-less portfolio method. And further, the example it goes through is of a binomial 1-period model, so it doesn't really help me much as I have to consider a 2-period model in this question.

If my calculations are correct, I have $\$1.87522...$ as my price for the option in risk-neutral arguments.

So my risk-less argument should give me the same value for the option but with the information I am given, and the scarce information found on the internet, I don't know what to do....

Can someone please tell me how this works for that part please? Thanks...

Comment: Which book are you using? To do binomial on 2 steps, just draw the tree for these two steps, and do this backwards. You know payoffs at the very end, for all (how many) possible different final stock prices.

Comment: Hi, the notes are prepared by my prof, but he said that it is based on Tomas Bjork's "Arbitrage theory in continuous time." I did that method(tree backwards) for the risk-neutral bit. I find the option values at N=2(N is the period) for each nodes and then find the martingale probabilities denoted $q_u$ and $q_d$ in my notes, use them to find the price at N=1, and then N=0. My question for risk"LESS" version is, how exactly does this work? I used $q_u$, $q_d$ for the risk-neutral argument but what does this become in the risk-less argument? How exactly do I proceed?

Comment: I thought, risk-neutral method is: get martingale measure, compute the expectation. Risk-less method is: compute which amount of Stock (Delta) you need to hold in each node to hedge, assume that you do this transaction, and see how much of initial capital is needed.

Comment: For the $\Delta$ method, the example in my notes with N=1 assumes that the values at the nodes $S_1(u),S_1(d)$ gives $S_1(u)\Delta-\Phi(S_1(u))=S_1(d)\Delta-\Phi(S_1(d))$ and then solves for $\Delta$. How do I do this for N=2? I have $3$ nodes now, yes? $S_2(uu),S_2(ud),S_2(dd)$. I tried doing it separately, for $S_2(uu),S_2(ud)$ and $S_2(ud),S_2(dd)$ and got different $\Delta$s...and what would these 2 $\Delta$s do to calculate the final option price at N=0...? I'm sorry I am very very lost....

Answer (score 1):

A similar example has been solved at this file.  I used it to solve your problem and indeed the answers using both Risk Neutral and Riskless (No arbitrage) answers were identical.  I have attached the image where it is easy to show the binomial tree and explain.  Goodluck.

http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~sf/20912lecture8.pdf

[image]